# Long polling with Ajax with sleep()/time_sleep_until() in while() loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, symfony

I'm willing to set up a long polling Ajax call to check for orders in my e-commerce web app. There is a specificity in this application in the way that customers are able to place order in the future. As such, in the admin panel, we have past orders and futures orders (that can be 2 months or 20 minutes in the future).

Basically, I want the admin user in the back-end to be warned as soon as a future order comes to an end (the future date reaches the current time). To proceed, I make the user admin doing an Ajax call (as soon as they are connected to the admin) to the server to check for futures orders to arrive. This Ajax call is a long polling request as the call waits for the server to deliver result. If server has nothing to offer, the request keeps pending until there is an order to show.

**Ajax request**

```
    (function poll() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('commande_check') }}',
                method: 'post',
                success: function(r) {
                    if(r.ids) alert('New order!'); // I've simplified this part of the code to make it clean, admin are actually warned through Node.JS server
                },
                error: function() {},
                complete: poll
            });
        }, 5000);
    })();
```

**{{ path('commande_check') }}** (edited from **Edit2**)

```
public function checkAction(Request $request)
{

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $ids = array();
        while(!$ids)
        {
            $ids = $em->getRepository('PaymentBundle:Commande')->findNewestOrders(new \DateTime());
            if($ids)
                break;
            else
                time_sleep_until(time() + self::SECONDS_TO_SLEEP);
        }

        if($ids)
        {
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'ids' => $ids
            ));
        }
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
        return $response;
    }

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(405);
    return $response;
}
```

**findNewestOrder() method**

```
public function findNewestOrders(\DateTime $datetime)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                  ->select('c.id')
                  ->leftJoin('Kt\PaymentBundle\Entity\Paiement', 'p', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'p.id = c.paiement')
                  ->andWhere('p.etat = 0')
                  ->where("DATE_FORMAT(c.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = :date")
                  ->setParameter('date', $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i'))
                  ->andWhere('c.kbis IS NULL')
                  ->andWhere('c.notif = 0')
                  ->getQuery();

    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

My problem is the alert sometimes never get shown whereas the record in the DB gets updated. The weirdest things is it sometimes happens even when I've leaved the page making the Ajax call like if it keeps running in the background. I think the problem comes from the `time_sleep_until()` function. I tried with `sleep(self::SECOND_TO_SLEEP)` but the problem was the same.

Any help would by gladly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I sense there is something to do with `connection_status()` function as the while loop appears to continue even if the user has switched page causing the field `notif` to be updated in the background.

**Edit 2**

[As per my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206054/2788131), I've managed to overcome this situation but the problem still remains. The admin does get the notification properly. However, I do know the Ajax call still keeps going on as the request has been made.

My problem is now: **could this result in a server resources overload?**
I'm willing to start a bounty on this one as I'm eager to know the best solution to achieve what I want.

Comment: I suggest you to make in a waiting condition the client and not the server...

Comment: What's `findNewestOrders()` doing?

Comment: @Matteo > What do you mean by making in a wayting condition the client and not the server?

Comment: @Marek > It fetches the ID's of the order that arrives to expiration (the futures date reaches the present date).

Comment: don't `make PHP pauses the script` but  make scheduled call via js something like `window.setInterval`

Comment: @Matteo > Thanks for your advice, but this would be no longer long polling, am I right? If I do so, I'll end up with many ajax calls in the browser debug bar and that's a way I wouldn't like to the investigate. What's wrong in making PHP pauses the script?

Comment: I don't understand why you are avoiding using the ajax with setInterval. That is a much more proper way of checking a status it runs the server side only when necessary. You could also have a separate CRON job that would ping it in the case that the admin is not logged in, but I don't know if that is what you're thinking.

Comment: @CayceK ajax with setInterval is very inefficient and will result in far more load both on the client and the server. Long-polling is the right choice here (unless websockets is an option)

Comment: @Steve I'm not a php dev, so bear with me, i may ask stupid questions. But, `findNewestOrders(new \DateTime())` If you're creating a new dateTime every time you call this method, wouldn't it never find new records because you keep increasing the datetime rather than using the datetime
 when the ajax request started?

Comment: sleep is always true forever UNLESS it the sleep fails

Comment: also... assuming his function is correct the `findNewestOrders` would find any and all order that are not fulfilled and equal to or less than current time.

Comment: my Problem is if the user leaves how are you supposed to end long-polling. Theoretically this would run on the server forever if no new order is ever made.

Comment: The longpolling script server-side should never run longer than 30 seconds (or some set amount of time). His current version of course doesn't do that, so that's a problem too.

Comment: Many thanks guys for commenting my issue.
@CayceK > As per Kevin B states, I keep thinking long polling is the right choice to accomplish what I want. As for `sleep()`, I thought it returns `false` if the client abort the script, doesn't it? And if the user leaves, shouldn't the long polling stops as the Ajax request no longer pending?
@Kevin B > I invoke new `DateTime` object in order to check for every minute if there is an order corresponding to that minute. So yes, it does find new records. How my long polling server-side script running for more than 30s is a problem?

Comment: the amount of time that it runs isn't the problem. The problem stems from the fact that there is no way of ending it unless a new record is found. The ajax request not listening anymore won't make the server stop running. (unless, i'm totally wrong and php handles that differently than i'm used to)

Comment: @KevinB > Right, this is something I had not in mind actually. My goal is to limit number of ajax requests made. Otherwise, I would have done regular polling every X seconds to the server but this is not what I want.

Comment: `where("DATE_FORMAT(c.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = :date")`  should this not be `<=` ??

Comment: @CayceK > No, because as the SQL query is made every minute at most, I need to check the exact value of the field `c.date`. If I do `<=`, I'll get all past orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I think I got it all wrong.*

The intent of long-polling Ajax is **not** that there is only one connection that stays opened such as websockets (as I thought it did). One would have to make several requests but much less than regular polling.

- **Regular polling**

The intent for Ajax regular polling is one makes a request to the server every 2 or 3 seconds to have a semblance of real-time notification. These would result in many Ajax calls during one minute.

- **Long polling**

As the server is **waiting** for new data to be passed on to the browser, one would need to make only a minimal number of requests per minute. As I'm checking in the database for new order every minute, using long polling can make me lower the number of requests per minute to `1`.

- *In my case*

In consequence, the specificity of the application makes the use of Ajax long-polling **unnecessary**. As soon as a MySQL query has been made for a specific minute, there is no need for the query to run again in the same minute. That means I can do regular polling with an interval of 60000 ms. There's also no need to use `sleep()` nor `time_sleep_until()`.

Here's how I ended up doing it:

**JS polling function**

```
    (function poll() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('commande_check') }}',
            method: 'post',
            success: function(r) {
                if(r.ids)
                    alert('New orders');
            },
            error: function() {},
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(poll, 60000);
            }
        });
    })();
```

**{{ path('commande_check') }}**

```
public function checkAction(Request $request)
{

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $ids = $em->getRepository('PaymentBundle:Commande')->findNewestOrders(new \DateTime());

        if($ids)
        {
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'ids' => $ids
            ));
        }
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
        return $response;
    }
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(405);
    return $response;
}
```

As such, I end up with one request per minute that will check for new orders.

Thanks @SteveChilds, @CayceK and @KevinB for their kind advice.

Answer (score 1):

In general for this problem it is kinda rough to say. We don't have a lot of information as to exactly what your other functions do. Like `findNewestOrders`...

We can assume that it pulls all new orders that have yet to be fulfilled by the admin and therefore will be displayed. However, if it is looking only for orders that are exactly equal they will never be filled.

Theoretically this will run forever if no new order ever is filed. You have no time limit on this so it is possible that the server feels like you have a case in which `while` will never be `false` and executes an exceeded execution time.

**As per your comment**

[time_sleep_until](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php)

`Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`

The only way it would ever fail is if the function itself failed or some server side issue caused a failure return. As you never officially visit the page and no act of leaving your ajax'd page submits a failure response it should never really fail.

I think it might be more wise to look into doing a CRON job for this and have a database of incomplete orders that you query instead. The CRON can run every minute and populate the database. The run on the server would not be that great as it would most likely take no more than 30 seconds any way.

Long-polling may be a great idea for many functions, but I'm not wholly confident it is in the case. I would seriously recommend setInterval as the load on the server and client would not be that great in a 30 seconds call every minute or two. That is your call in the end.

Comment: @Steve and `sleep()` is identical to `time_sleep_until`

Comment: Many thanks for answering. I actually hesitated with a CRON job. I decided to go with long polling as I thought it suited my needs more than CRON jobs. BTW, `sleep()` is no strictly identical to `time_sleep_until()` as the argument is not the same and mostly, the return value is different on success (0 for the former, TRUE for the latter). And I've read many times that `setInterval()` is less suitable than `setTimeout()` for Ajax request polling (what if the request takes longer than the value of `setInterval()` for instance?)

Comment: @Steve That is correct, if the request takes longer than the timeout consistently for a period of time, you'll end up with a backlog of queued requests. That's less likely to happen with a 30 second interval, but still possible.

Comment: those are both true statements and valid thoughts. I don't really see your script running longer than a minute if you go rid of the while statement and instead just checked every minute like you are doing already. But it is understandable of you avoiding it so I won't push that any more. It is understandable that you decided one over the other, but maybe relook into CRON it could be better in the end. But have you thought to try and add your own max time to run for this script? That way you can at least guarantee it falls out and makes sure that the user is still requesting the call.

Comment: setTimeout vs setInterval is somewhat irrelevant in this case, it's more about how you handle it on the server that changes the functionality.

Comment: I totally agree with @KevinB as such my problem comes from the server-side PHP script that keeps running in background on page switch, updating the field of the order being found and make the user **not** be notified about it. What about `connection_status()` and `connection_aborted()` functions? I sense I should enquiry to these.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would check frequently rather than have one request which runs for a long time - its not really ideal to have long running processes like this as they tie up server connections and really, its just bad practice. Plus the browser may well time the connection out, which is why you may not be seeing the responses you expect.

Have you tried changing the ajax call so it calls in say, every 60 seconds (or however often you want), checks for new orders since the last time it was polled (simply keep a track of this in the page / HTML5 local storage so it persists across pages and pass it in the ajax request as a parameter) and then simply returns an indication of yes there have been new orders, or no there hasn't?

You can then display a message if there have been new orders.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to overcome this bug but without digging deeply in the problem.

I have separated the code that updates the `notif` field from the code that fetch new orders. In that way, the `while` loop still goes on but cannot update the field.

The field is therefore updated on success of the first ajax call by making a new ajax request to update the field. Therefore, the admin always receives the notification.

I just have to enquiry on a memory/thread level to see what consumption of resources this loop uses.

As no solution has been found despites my workaround for the initial bug, I won't accept my answer as the problem remains still.

Many thanks for all the help on that question.